# Securing Geode on JMX level

Tags: gemfire, geode

I read several resources how to secure Geode components, pulse being one of them. I think I understood how Apache Shiro comes into play. But from my understanding JMX and RMI are the critical part where an attacker could access mbeans and interfere with or even manipulate the data in my distributed cache.

The company I work at demands for transport encryption and if possible "client" authentication. Is this supported in the current Geode 1.1.x ? I thought about giving `com.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl.need.client.auth` a try but found no information about Geode supporting it.

Answer (score 1):

When you configure `security-manager` in geode, everything flows through the [SecurityManager](http://geode.apache.org/docs/guide/11/managing/security/implementing_authentication.html) (including JMX, REST).

Transport encryption is also supported, please see [docs](http://geode.apache.org/docs/guide/11/managing/security/ssl_overview.html).